# Double BarLegend for Geo* plots

Tags: code-request, geography, geographics

I am trying to create a `GeoRegionValuePlot` based interface and I have a few unresolved items. This post is mostly about the use of a double `BarLegend` such that it appears as a single `BarLegend`.

```
(*ctrSA=EntityList[EntityClass["Country","SouthAmerica"]]
*)

ctrSA = DeleteCases[
  EntityList[EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"]]
  , _?(MemberQ[{Entity["Country", "FalklandIslands"], 
       Entity["Country", "FrenchGuiana"]}, #] &)
  ]
```

I have manually deleted two countries as curated data for these entities is sparse but not always. Here is a visual output of these entities.

[image]

---

Next, I choose an `EntityProperty`, a color scheme, and find the minimum and maximum values for the countries in question setting the missing entries to zero. For `Tooltip` purposes, I need country names as well as a formatted property label called `proplabel`

```
cProperty = "HDI"
cScheme = "TemperatureMap"
minmax = MinMax@(QuantityMagnitude@#[cProperty] & /@ 
     ctrSA) /. _Missing :> 0
qm = QuantityMagnitude@#[cProperty] & /@ ctrSA /. _Missing :> 0
cnames = #["Name"] & /@ ctrSA
proplabel = StringReplace[EntityProperty["Country", cProperty]["Label"]
  , k : {StartOfString | WhitespaceCharacter ~~ WordCharacter} -> 
   ToUpperCase[k]
  ]
```

---

Plotting:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[Tooltip[#
     , Labeled[#["Name"]
      , QuantityMagnitude@#[cProperty]]] ->
    #[cProperty] & /@ ctrSA
 , PlotLegends -> {
   Placed[BarLegend[{cScheme, minmax}
     , LegendLabel -> Placed["Country", {Above, Right}]
     , "TickSide" -> Right
     , "TickLengths" -> 5
     , Ticks -> Transpose[{qm, cnames }]
     , FrameStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.0]]
     ], {1.15, 0.5}],
   Placed[BarLegend[{cScheme, minmax}
     , LegendLabel -> Placed[proplabel, {Above, Left}]
     , "TickSide" -> Left
     , "TickLengths" -> 5
     , FrameStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.0]]
     ], {1, .5}]
   }
 , ColorFunction -> cScheme
 (*,GeoLabels\[Rule]True*)
 , LabelStyle -> {Black, 10}
 , ImageSize -> Large
 , PlotLabel -> Style[proplabel, 16
   , Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"]
 ]
```

[image]

**Questions**

1. How do I nudge the bar legends to the left together without the manual placement and tweaking?
2. How should legend labels be placed such that these are readable and don't interfere with positioning of legends especially when other properties with longer names are used? For instance, try: "MerchantShips" and "TotalFertilityRate". I have tried splitting words and put them in a column, but that still messes the alignment of legends.
3. For such `Geo*` plots, it is inevitably the case that many entries get clustered on the legend and the displayed text becomes unreadable. Any pointers/workarounds about that would be helpful. I haven't thought much or tried anything significant in this regard yet.
4. If I use all the countries on the continent i.e., not delete entries and set missing property entries to zero then the legends start at zero. This clusters the entries even more but more importantly the map colors don't scale along with the legend. What is the proper way to handle missing items without changing code and scaling map colors?

Points 2,4 are more important than others. Point 3 requires more effort so I will be indebted if you can offer a solution. Point 1 should be easy but I can't figure it out.

I have learned the undocumented techniques that appear in `Red` from various posts on this forum.

Thanks for your help.